# How to find the interval of convergence of $\sum \:_{n=0}^{\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{1}{\:\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{\:n!}\right)\left(x+2\right)^n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I managed to find the radius of convergence ($R=1$) therefore I know the convergence interval is $(-3; -1)$. The problem is that I don't know how to check the cases when $|x-x_0| = R$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\:\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{\:n!}\right)\left(x+2\right)^n$$

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am not entire sure about my answer**

but i think
for $x=-1$ we can say that if the initial series was converges then also the $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{n!}) + \frac{1}{n!}$
would converge, and that's a contradiction, hence at $x=-1$ it doesn't converge.

For $x=-3$ try to use Leibniz criterion.

Comment: your argument works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

When $x=-1$, we need to analyse the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{n!}\right)$. Since
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} 
\dfrac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{n!}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ne 0, \infty
$$

we conclude that $\sum \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{n!}\right)$ and $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ have the same nature (divergent).

When $x=-3$, since $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}}-\frac{1}{n!}\right)$ tends to zero and is eventually decreasing, you can use Liebnitz criteria and conclude for convergence.